# Windows CE 5 batch IF EXISTS

Tags: batch-file, windows-ce

I'm trying to run a batch file on a WINCE device that will ping another networked device and capture the results in a text file.
However, whenever I try to execute the section that checks to see if the log file already exists, I get this error:

```
IF: incorrect command syntax
```

Can anyone shed some light as to why?
Here is the bit that creates the text file to log the results. It may or may not be worth mentioning, but it works fine on a windows 7 PC:

```
SET DATETIME=%date:~0,2%\%date:~3,2%\%date:~6,4% 0%time:~1,1%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%    
if NOT exist %DATEVARIABLE%-log.txt type "New Log" > %DATEVARIABLE%-log.txt
```

Thanks
Doug

Comment: Where is `%DATEVARIABLE%` ??

Answer (score 0):

Something looks like this :

```
@echo off
SET "DATETIME=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%_%time:~1,1%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%" 
echo "%DATETIME%"
pause   
if NOT exist "%DATETIME%-log.txt" echo "New Log" > "%DATETIME%-log.txt"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks Hackoo for getting back to me - it turns out I think the problem is with the use of dates & times.
I can't seem to use a date or time on WINCE - no probs on the desktop tho..
MS says that `date /t` and `time /t` does the trick, but this comes with all of the illegal characters (yyyy\dd\mm & hh:mm:ss)..

Comment: @Doug So, your issue is fixed or not yet ?

Comment: No, just can't figure it out - it's doing my head right in! haha!!